# Why Won't my class work?

Tags: php, class

Does anybody know why my code doesn't work, i try running it but it doesn't work, when i put it online it says the page cannot load. Is there something i need to add or what? I can't get it to work for some reason.

```
class Network {
    public $LastLocate = 0;
    public $LastLocate2 = 0;
    public $ipSet = false;
    public $Sock = array();
    public $Sock2 = array();
    public $xSock = array("174.36.242.24", "174.36.242.25", "174.36.242.26", "174.36.242.27", "174.36.242.32", "174.36.242.33", "174.36.242.34", "174.36.242.35", "174.36.242.40", "174.36.242.41", "174.36.242.42", "174.36.242.43", "69.4.231.248", "69.4.231.249", "69.4.231.250", "69.4.231.251");
    public $xSock2 = array("208.43.218.80", "208.43.218.81", "208.43.218.82", "208.43.218.83", "174.36.56.200", "174.36.56.201", "174.36.56.202", "174.36.56.203", "174.36.4.144", "174.36.4.145", "174.36.4.146", "174.36.4.147", "174.36.56.184", "174.36.56.185", "174.36.56.186", "174.36.56.187");
    public $SockStatus = array(400, 401, 402, 403, 410, 411, 412, 413, 420, 421, 422, 423, 430, 431, 432, 433);

    public function GetDom($arg1){
        if ($arg1 == 8){
            return (0);
        }
        return ((($arg1)<8) ? 3 : (($arg1 & 96) >> 5));
    }

    public function GetPort($arg1){
        if ((integer)$arg1 == 8){
            return (10000);
        }
        return ((((integer)$arg1)<8) ? ((10000 - 1) + (integer)$arg1) : ((10000 + 7) + ((integer)$arg1 % 32)));
    }

    public function randomFloat(){
        $n = "0.".rand(0,9);
        return $n;
    }
    public function setIps(){
        $local2 = array();
        $local3 = 0;
        $local1 = 0;
        while ($local1 < $this->xservers){
            $local2 = array();
            $local3 = 0;
            while ($local3 < $this->xips)
            {
                $v = (($local1 * $this->xips) + $local3);
                if ($this->SockStatus[$v] != 0){
                    array_push($local2, $this->xSock[(($local1 * $this->xips) + $local3)]);
                }
                $local3++;
            }
            if (count($local2) > 0){
                $this->Sock[$local1] = $local2[round($this->randomFloat() * count($local2))];
            }
            $local1++;
        }
    }
    echo $this->Sock[$this->GetDom(5)];
    }
?>
```

Comment: I know: because the code is bad. Honestly, the question with such quality deserves to be answered in such way. You did not even try to explain what do you mean by "does not work", nor you tried to solve that yourself. Read [faq] before asking question again. This one probably will be closed soon.

Answer (score 2):

At the very end of your class you have this echo statement sitting inside the class (not inside any kind of function):

```
echo $this->Sock[$this->GetDom(5)];
```

You should move it into its own function:

```
function output()
{
    return $this->Sock[$this->GetDom(5)];
}
```

Then call it from outside the class:

```
$class = new Network();
$output = $class->output();

echo $output;
```